# I can't save AppStore Version Release

Tags: app-store

This is my first time uploading an app to the app store.

**Error:**
Your changes could not be saved. Try again later.

**Version Release**

Manually release this version (Default Selected)

Automatically release this version (I can't select this.)

Automatically release this version after App Review, no earlier than

Comment: I am also get the same problem when i try to save using "Automatically release this version after App Review, no earlier than" it gives error  did you find the solution?